# Validating action attributes on thousands of forms

Tags: html, validation

I've inherited a Courseware CD with thousands of `<form action="page.html" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Go"></form>` buttons.

Some of those forms are pointing to pages that don't exist and I'd really like to use an automated testing tool/crawler to test them out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: preferably, none. Since this seems like something there should already be tools for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WATIR or WATIN could assist you in this, especially if the submit button's value is always "GO" or something similar.

Another option is to create a small app, which reads in each html file, finds the form element, grabs the action value and sees if said file exists, if not it logs it and then goes onto the next file